# How to apply Fubini here

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ and $g$ be integrable functions on the measure space $(X, \mathcal M, \mu)$ with the property that

$$
\mu(\{f > t\} \triangle \{g > t\}) = 0
$$

for $\lambda$-a.e. $t \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $f = g\;$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Here, $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure and $\triangle$ denotes symmetric difference.

My thoughts: I'm quite certain I should apply Fubini here to some $F: X \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. But I'm not sure how to choose $F$ and, even if I did have an $F$ in hand, I don't know how to apply Fubini without some completeness or $\sigma$-finite condition on $(X, \mathcal M, \mu)$.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Fubini.

Let $D_t = f^{-1}(t,\infty) \triangle g^{-1}(t,\infty)$. Note that if $s<t$, then $D_t \subset D_s$. It follows that $\mu D_t =  0$ for all $t$ (not just ae. [$\lambda$]).

Let $q_n$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $\Delta_n = f^{-1}(q_n,\infty) \cap g^{-1}(-\infty, q_n]$. Let $\Delta = \cup_n \Delta_n$. Then we have $\Delta = \{ x | f(x) > g(x) \}$. Also, note that $\Delta_n \subset D_{q_n}$.

Suppose $\mu \Delta>0$, then $\mu \Delta_n >0$ for some $n$, which contradicts $\mu D_{q_n} = 0$. Hence $\mu \Delta = 0$.

Exactly the same analysis applies with $f,g$ swapped, hence $f(x) = g(x)$ ae. [$\mu$].

Comment: Upon further thought, I'm not seeing why $D_t \subset D_s$ if $s < t$. Take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \lceil x \rceil$. Then $D_{\frac{3}{2}} \not\subset D_{\frac{1}{2}}$.